# Storing coefficients from a Regression in Stata

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata

I am trying to store the coefficients from a simulated regression in a variable b1 and b2 in the code below, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this. I've tried using `return scalar b1 = _b[x1]` and `return scalar b2 = _b[x2]`, from the `rclass()` function, but that didn't work. Then I tried using `scalar b1 = e(x1)` and `scalar b2 = e(x2)`, from the `eclass()` function and also wasn't successful.

The goal is to use these stored coefficients to estimate some value (say rhat) and test the standard error of rhat.

Here's my code below:

```
program montecarlo2, eclass  
    clear  
    version 11  
    drop _all  
    set obs 20  
    gen x1 = rchi2(4) - 4  
    gen x2 = (runiform(1,2) + 3.5)^2  
    gen u = 0.3*rnormal(0,25) + 0.7*rnormal(0,5)  
    gen y = 1.3*x1 + 0.7*x2 + 0.5*u  
* OLS Model  
    regress y x1 x2             
    scalar b1 = e(x1)  
    scalar b2 = e(x2)  
end
```

I want to do something like,

rhat = b1 + b2, and then test the standard error of rhat.

Comment: Quite a lot of fantasy syntax here such as `e(x1)`. But `scalar b1 = _b[x1]` etc. would work either within the program or after it. It is not clear that you need to declare the program either `eclass` or `rclass` if all you want to access the coefficient estimates. Off-topic on CV regardless, so I'm voting to migrate to SO. See help in the CV Help Center on software-specific questions. .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Nick! It works now. But a quick follow up question, I'm trying to store the scalars in a variable, such as, rhat. I'm trying rhat = display b1 + b2, but I get an error saying the command isn't recognized. Any suggestions on how to address this?

Comment: Use the lincom command to get the sum, which you can then use for the hypothesis test. No need to store it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's hack a bit at your program:

Version 1

```
program montecarlo2
    clear  
    version 11  
    set obs 20  
    gen x1 = rchi2(4) - 4  
    gen x2 = (runiform(1,2) + 3.5)^2  
    gen u = 0.3*rnormal(0,25) + 0.7*rnormal(0,5)  
    gen y = 1.3*x1 + 0.7*x2 + 0.5*u  
* OLS Model  
    regress y x1 x2             
end
```

I cut `drop _all` as unnecessary given the `clear`. I cut the `eclass`. One reason for doing that is the `regress` will leave e-class results in its wake any way. Also, you can if you wish add

```
scalar b1 = _b[x1] 
scalar b2 = _b[x2] 
scalar r = b1 + b2
```

either within the program after the `regress` or immediately after the program runs.

Version 2

```
program montecarlo2, eclass 
    clear  
    version 11  
    set obs 20  
    gen x1 = rchi2(4) - 4  
    gen x2 = (runiform(1,2) + 3.5)^2  
    gen u = 0.3*rnormal(0,25) + 0.7*rnormal(0,5)  
    gen y = 1.3*x1 + 0.7*x2 + 0.5*u  
* OLS Model  
    regress y x1 x2         
    * stuff to add    
end
```

Again, I cut `drop _all` as unnecessary given the `clear`. Now the declaration `eclass` is double-edged. It gives the programmer scope for their program to save e-class results, but you have to say what they will be. That's the stuff to add indicated by a comment above.

Warning: I've tested none of this. I am not addressing the wider context. @Dimitriy V. Masterov's suggestion of `lincom` is likely to be a really good idea for whatever your problem is.